# How to retrieve INSTALLED applications in Blackberry programatically

Tags: blackberry

I have the code to retrieve the currently running applications in Blackberry.

And, I have also used `CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles()` but I am not able to retrieve the application names.

Please help.

```java
ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
int[] handle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles();
ApplicationDescriptor[] appDes = appMan.getVisibleApplications();

for (int i = appDes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
{
    String moduleName = appDes[i].getModuleName();
    String name = appDes[i].getName();
    System.out.println("**********************"+moduleName+"        "+
        name+"*********************");
}
for (int i= handle.length -1; i>=0; --i)
{
    System.out.println("*************"+handle[i]+"***********");            
}

System.out.println("**Code**"+CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(70) + 
    "**************");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
int[] handle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles();                    
for(int i=0; i<handle.length; i++){  
    ApplicationDescriptor[] app_descriptors = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(handle[i]);               
        if(app_descriptors != null){ 
            for(int j=0; j< app_descriptors.length; j++){
                 String moduleName = app_descriptors[i].getModuleName();
                 String name = app_descriptors[i].getName();
                 //here the String variable name will give you all the app names installed on your devise.

            } 
        }               
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know, there's an error here. app_descriptors[i] should be app_descriptors[j].